# Get #prefixed words in a string and replace them to clickable links

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, hashtag

I have some strings with #prefixed words in it

**For Example:**

Comment 1: I am a #smart person.

Comment 2: I love to #code new things.

Comment 3: I have a #new concept.

I want it to find the #items in this strings, which I am doing with the below section.

```
var result       = $.grep(comment.split(' '), function(item) {
    var hashWords = /^#/.test(item);
    return hashWords;
});
```

I will get each #words from the above comments with the above code

#smart

#code

#new

But I wanted it to replace to clickable links

Comment 1: I am a [#smart](https://www.google.com?hashtag=smart) person.

Comment 2: I love to [#code](https://www.google.com?hashtag=code) new things.

Comment 3: I have a [#new](https://www.google.com?hashtag=link) concept.

Please help me to figure out a solution for this as I am new to jquery.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function replacePrefix(target) {
    var regex = /\#(\w+)/gmi;
    var subst = `<a href='https://www.google.com?hashtag=$1'>#$1</a>`;
    var myText;
    $(target).each(function(i, el) {
      myText = $(el).html();
      $(el).html(myText.replace(regex, subst));
    });
  }

  replacePrefix(".comment");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="comment">I am a #smart person.</div>
  <div class="comment">I love to #code new things.</div>
  <div class="comment">I have a #new concept.</div>
</div>
```

Pass in a Selector or an Element and it will iterate over each, looking for prefixes, `#new` for example, and replaces them with the HTML:

```
<a href='https://www.google.com?hashtag=new'>#new</a>
```